# Agreement of Two Distributions

Tags: vectors

I have two distributions which are defined by vectors $\vec u, \vec v$ of equal length $n$. The elements of the vectors are constrained such that $0\le u_i,v_i\le1$.

The values of the elements have a meaning. If they equal one then a thing is "okay"; if they equal zero then a thing is "not okay". My goal is to define a metric which captures how much $\vec u, \vec v$ agree on what is okay versus not okay.

One way to do this would be to take:

$$\frac{\vec u \cdot \vec v}{n}$$

So that a value of 1 indicates the maximal possible agreement whereas the value of 0 represents no agreement.

Is there a name for this test? Is there an established way or ways of doing this?

Comment: What is your definition of $dim(\vec{u})$ ? Its length ? In this case $dim(\vec{u})+dim(\vec{v})=2 dim(\vec{u})$ always.

Comment: Yes, @JeanMarie, that is length. I'm going to edit the answer so it is unambiguous.

Answer (score 1):

Your idea has something to do with [cosine similarity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosine_similarity), which itself is a non-centered **correlation coefficient**, defined by

$$\rho=\frac{\vec u \cdot \vec v}{\|u\|\|v\|} \ \ \ (1)$$

(which is a cosine in nD: the closer the vectors, the closer to 1 is their cosine).

The advantage of (1) is that it is homogeneous (independent of the units taken for your data, e.g., centimeters vs. inches...).

Comment: Of course; I've fixed the $2n$ factor now.